# Remove @IBInspectable error: Failed to set () user defined inspected property on (UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibinspectable

I added an `@IBInspectable` property named `style` as an `extension` to `UIView`. I refactored it because it interferes with `UITableView.style`. I am getting this error, I know exactly what the error means, but can't figure out how to actually stop it looking for `style`. It doesn't cause a fatal error, but it is very annoying. Does anyone know how to remove it?

My refactored `@IBInspectable` code:

```
// Global variable to produce a unique address as the AssociatedObjectHandle
var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

public extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var styleName: String {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as? String ?? ""
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried:

1: Clean and build

2: Deleting the emulator files

3: Quitting XCode

Answer (score 1):

Needed to remove the property from the User Defined Runtime Attributes, in the Identity Inspector on the Storyboard. Figured this out, shortly after posting the question.

As shown below:

[image]

Comment: Had similar situation.  Had created a special subclass of UIView with an IBInspectable property.  Used this in IB.  Then copied the view in IB because it had coloring the way I wanted, but didn't need the special feature - so demoted it down to a UIView.  So, now IB was complaining because UIView couldn't set this property - and hadn't realized that the property was there from the copy.  Removing it like it says in this post cleaned up the error report.